# Adding the button from another class but none of parameters goes trough just a plain button

Tags: java, swing, class, jbutton

To begin with I'm in this just a few days so I am sorry if this is a silly question, I did my search but I didn't find what I was looking for.

Simply said, I've got a class like this:

```
public class logout extends JButton {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -4813329911065574369L;
public static JButton logout = new JButton("Izloguj se");

public logout() 
{
  //parameters like font, foreground etc
}
```

And when I try to call it in another class, like this:

```
    ctrl.add(prikaz.logout.logout);
```

I get an old plain button with text I defined in class but none of the parameters I defined for it.

I know I can add the button with its settings if I do something like:

```
JPanel lgtBtn = new logout();
```

But I would like to do it directly with add.

Comment: *But i would like to do it directly with add* - it doesn't work that way. If you want to change the properties of an object then you need to create an instance of that object and then set the properties. The code you posted here is complete wrong and should not be used. There is no need for a class to extend JButton.

Comment: You're creating ***two*** JButtons, one the logout object itself, which doesn't have any properties changed but which is displayed, and the other the logout field within the logout class, which does have its properties changed but which is never changed. Don't do this. Do as @camickr suggests and don't extend JButton, but rather create JButtons and set their properties as needed. Only extend if you are going to be changing innate behaviors of the object (overriding one of its methods).

Comment: Also, you should not be giving a field the same name as the class itself as this will only serve to confuse, and  you should learn and follow Java naming conventions: class names begin with an upper case letter always.

Comment: Maybe what you are trying to do is create a `Factory`. A Factory allows you to invoke a static method and the method will return an instance of the object. The factor method can then custom the properties of the component. Search the web for "Factory Pattern".

Comment: Thank you both for comments and suggestions, i will take them for good and do as you said. Factory does seem like something i had in mind i will take my time and learn about it.
Thanks!

Comment: Java programming conventions have classes starting with an upper case letter, and variables and methods start with lower case letters. This makes the code easier to read and debug, especially when you ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the `logout` button with:

```
public static JButton logout = new JButton("Izloguj se");
```

This creates a new `JButton` with the specified text.  But then the class you are in *also* extends `JButton`, and it is set up in the constructor.  So you have two `JButton`s, but you only ever reference the one that is not set up.  I would just get rid of the line of code above, and reference the button as `prikaz.logout` (not `prikaz.logout.logout`).